# Access specific child div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to know how to access a specific element in a `div` when foreach-ing

Here is some code

HTML

```
<div class="row menu-filter-items">
    <div class="col-md-4 margin-b-30 menu-item">
        <a href="#" class="menu-grid">
            <img src="images/img-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"/>
            <div class="menu-grid-desc">                               
            <!--  <span class="price float-right">$9.50</span> -->
                <h4 class="a" id="title">Restaurant y</h4>
                <p>
                    Description
                </p>
            </div>                           
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
 $('#search').keyup(function(e){
     var current_query = $('#search').val();
         if(current_query != null)
         {
             $("div.menu-filter-items").hide();
             $("div.menu-filter-items div.menu-item").each(function(){
                 var current_keyword = $(this).children('#title').text();

                 alert(current_keyword);
                 if (current_keyword.indexOf(current_query) >=0)
                 {
                     $("div.menu-filter-items").show();         
                 }

             });


         }
         else
         {
             $("div.menu-filter-items").show();
         }

});
```

I want to access the H4 balise but I couldn't
Help please 
thank you

Comment: `$('.menu-filter-items').find('#h4')` ??

Comment: $(this).find('#title').text();

Comment: oh no.. Sorry @freedomn-m it should be just `h4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
var current_keyword = $(this).find('#title').text();
```

instead of

```
var current_keyword = $(this).children('#title').text();
```

Comment: yes .find worked , but i've tried it before but it didn't , sure  I have done something wrong in another matter, thank you

Comment: If it worked then accept and upvote the answer for others

Comment: @saifiswinning11, i add an answer in order to help you see what's wrong with your code.

Comment: I have to wait 8 minutes

Comment: To improve this answer, it could use a description of the difference, otherwise this is essentially a code-only answer which is generally frowned-upon.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `find` method.

The `.children()` method allows us to search through the children of these elements in the `DOM` tree and construct a new `jQuery` object from the matching elements. The `.children()` method differs from `.find()` in that `.children()` only travels a single level down the DOM tree while `.find()` can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find to perform a search with Jquery lib.

See full doc here : https://api.jquery.com/find/

For your case; you can use :

```
$( "div.menu-filter-items" ).find( "h4" )
```